# View is not showing data after request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entity framework model as:

```
public class Campaign
{
 public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

 public ICollection<CampaignStation> Stations { get; set; } = new List<CampaignStation>();

 public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
}


public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Campaign> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Stations).WithOne(y => y.Campaign);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Orders).WithOne(y => y.Campaign);
    }
```

So I have a get controller to get results, and I get results as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Apparently the service is working correctly

Now in the view, the status shows an error:

[image]

But the header show status OK

[image]

I have no idea what is wrong. If I try to access a model property like

```
 <p>@Model.Select(x=> x.Name).ToString()</p>
```

It shows:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator`2[Project.Lib.Models.Campaign,System.String]

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var results = await _campaignsService.GetCampaignsAsync();
        return View(results);
    }
```

Service:

```
 public async Task<IList<Campaign>> GetCampaignsAsync()
    {
        return await _db.Campaigns 
        .Include(a => a.Agency)
        .Include(s => s.Stations)
        .ThenInclude(cs => cs.Station)
        .ToListAsync();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently is something with the EF Migration, I removed the collections and created a new migration and now it does not throw any error, it shows the Name property, etc. But now the question is, how can I return the list of my other two tables and not make any conflict? for some reason `public ICollection<CampaignStation> Stations { get; set; } = new List<CampaignStation>();` it is not working but as in my image, it is returning the list correctly!

Comment: Yes, but that throw an error: Cannot convert expression type string to return type bool, no idea why if the property is a string @viveknuna

Comment: Sorry my bad, I misunderstood. You need to do this .Select( x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault(y =>y)